# Can R read html-encoded emoji characters?

Tags: r, xml, emoji, html-encode, xml2

## Question

My question, explained below, is: 
**How can R be used to read a string that includes HTML emoji codes like `&#55358;&#56599;`?** 
I'd like to:
(1) represent the emoji symbol (e.g., as a unicode symbol: ) in the parsed string, **OR**
(2) convert it into its text equivalent ("`:hugging face:`")

## Background

I have an XML dataset of text messages (from the Android/iOS app [Signal](https://signal.org/)) that I am reading into R for a text mining project. The data look like this, with each text message represented in an `sms` node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!-- File Created By Signal -->
    <smses count="1">
        <sms protocol="0" address="+15555555555" contact_name="Jane Doe" date="1483256850399" readable_date="Sat, 31 Dec 2016 23:47:30 PST" type="1" subject="null" body="Hug emoji: &#55358;&#56599;" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" />
</smses>
```

## Problem

I am currently reading the data using the `xml2` package for R. When I use the `xml2::read_xml` function, however, I get the following error message:

```
Error in doc_parse_raw(x, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html,  : 
  xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 55358
```

Which, as I understand, indicates that the emoji character is not recognized as valid XML.

Using the `xml2::read_html` function *does* work, but drops the emoji character. A small example of this is here:

```
example_text <- "Hugging emoji: &#55358;&#56599;"
xml2::xml_text(xml2::read_html(paste0("<x>", example_text, "</x>")))
```

(Output: `[1] "Hugging emoji: "`)

This character *is* valid HTML -- Googling `&#55358;&#56599;` actually converts it in the search bar to the "hugging face" emoji, and brings up results relating to that emoji.

## Other information I've found that seems relevant to this question

I've been searching Stack Overflow, and have not found any questions relating to this particular issue. I've also not been able to find a table that straightforwardly gives HTML codes next to the emoji they represent, and so am not able to do an (albeit inefficient) conversion of these HTML codes to their textual equivalents in a big loop before parsing the dataset; for example, neither [this list](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) nor [its underlying dataset](http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/5.0/) seem to include the string `55358`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr:** the emoji aren't valid HTML entities; UTF-16 numbers have been used to build them instead of Unicode code points. I describe an algorithm at the bottom of the answer to convert them so that they are valid XML.

---

***Identifying the Problem***

R definitely handles emoji:

[image]

In fact, a few packages exist for handling emoji in R. For example, the [emojifont](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emojifont/vignettes/emojifont.html) and [emo](https://github.com/hadley/emo) packages both let you retrieve emoji based on Slack-style keywords.  It's just a question of getting your source characters through from the HTML-escaped format so that you can convert them.

`xml2::read_xml` seems to do fine with other HTML entities, like an ampersand or double quotes. I looked at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33288574/3246758) to see whether there were any XML-specific constraints on HTML entities, and it seemed like they were storing emoji fine. So I tried changing the emoji codes in your reprex to the ones in that answer:

```
body="Hug emoji: &#128512;&#128515;"
```

And, sure enough, they were preserved (though they're obviously not the hug emoji anymore):

```
> test8 = read_html('Desktop/test.xml')
> test8 %>% xml_child() %>% xml_child() %>% xml_child() %>% xml_attr('body')
[1] "Hug emoji: \U0001f600\U0001f603"
```

I looked up the hug emoji on [this page](http://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/1856/smileys-people/hugging-face), and the decimal HTML entity given there is *not* `&#55358;&#56599;`. It looks like the UTF-16 decimal codes for the emoji have been wrapped in `&#` and `;`.

**In conclusion, I think the answer is that your emoji are, in fact, not valid HTML entities. If you can't control the source, you might need to do some pre-processing to account for these errors.**

So, why does the browser convert them properly? I'm wondering if the browser is a little more flexible with these things and is making some guesses about what those codes could be. I'm just speculating, though.

---

***Converting UTF-16 to Unicode code points***

After some more investigation, it looks like valid emoji HTML entities use the Unicode code point (in decimal, if it's `&#...;`, or hex, if it's `&#x...;`). [*The Unicode code point is different from the UTF-8 or UTF-16 code.*](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/11/character-sets-encoding-emoji/) (That link explains a *lot* about how emoji and other characters are variously encoded, BTW! Good read.)

So we need to convert the UTF-16 codes used in your source data to Unicode code points. Referring to [this Wikipedia article on UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+10000_to_U+10FFFF), I've verified how it's done. Each Unicode code point (our target) is a 20-bit number, or five hex digits. When going from Unicode to UTF-16, you split it up into two 10-bit numbers (the middle hex digit gets cut in half, with two of its bits going to each block), do some maths on them and get your result).

Going backwards, as you want to, it's done like this:

- Your decimal UTF-16 number (which is in two separate blocks for now) is `55358 56599`
- Converting those blocks to hex (separately) gives `0x0d83e 0x0dd17`
- You subtract `0xd800` from the first block and `0xdc00` from the second to give `0x3e 0x117`
- Converting them to binary, padding them out to 10 bits and concatenating them, it's `0b0000 1111 1001 0001 0111`
- Then we convert that back to hex, which is `0x0f917`
- Finally, we add `0x10000`, giving `0x1f917`
- **Therefore, our (hex) HTML entity is `&#x1f917;`. Or, in decimal, `&#129303`**

So, to preprocess this dataset, you'll need to extract the existing numbers, use the algorithm above, then put the result back in (with one `&#...;`, not two).

---

***Displaying emoji in R***

As far as I'm aware, there's no solution to printing emoji in the R console: they always come out as `"U0001f600"` (or what have you). However, the packages I described above can help you plot emoji in some circumstances (I'm hoping to expand [ggflags](https://github.com/rensa/ggflags) to display arbitrary full-colour emoji at some point). They can also help you search for emoji to get their codes, but they can't get names given the codes AFAIK. But maybe you could try importing [the emoji list from `emojilib`](https://github.com/muan/emojilib/blob/master/emojis.json) into R and doing a join with your data frame, if you've extracted the emoji codes into a column, to get the English names.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Your answer gets me *much* farther along to understanding what is going on. I appreciate your work and help!

As you suggested, I can't control the dataset (unless I can get a PR accepted to the app itself). I'm trying to understand now how to get R to read decimal codes for characters -- I'm fine with the idea of running a regex find-and-replace on the file before parsing it, but I'm not sure what format to change the `&#...;` strings into. Would you have any suggestions?

Comment: No worries! It looks like using `&#...;` is actually fine—it's just that your source dataset is using the wrong `...`. I'm not sure what the relation between the UTF-16 decimal codes (which you're using) and the decimal HTML entities (which you ought to be using) is, but based on my previous work with [ggflags](https://github.com/rensa/ggflags), I'd guess that the emoji are in the same places but the block starts at a different number. I'll see if I can find out :)

Comment: ~~The alternative (and, now that I think about it, the easier solution) might be to try stripping out `&#` and `;`, converting the UTF-16 decimal codes to hex, and prepending `\U000`. Looking at that middle example in my answer, it seems like that's what `read_html` has done.~~ Actually, ignore that! I think you def need to convert the numbers.

Comment: Ugh, sorry—ignore that last comment. I think you def need to translate the numbers; it's def not as simple as changing them to hex and changing the `&#...;` to `/U000...`.

Comment: I'm grateful for your thoughts; thank you! When you say "convert the numbers," you mean from UTF-16 decimal code to htmlentities somehow, correct? Also, as you noted, `"\U0001f600\U0001f603"` doesn't actually display as the hug emoji when run in R. Are you aware of how to get the hug emoji to display? (If I can find a goal-place to get to, where the hug emoji does correctly display, I can try working backwards to find a way to get there).

Comment: I'm just updating my answer with some of that now :) As far as actually getting emoji to display (instead of the code), that's a separate issue.

Comment: That's fair; I'm happy to stick to one issue at at time! : )

Comment: Okay, I've done some research and described an algorithm to help you convert the UTF-16 numbers in your dataset to valid HTML entities (with Unicode code points). I think that should be all you need, provided you can translate my admittedly not codey instructions 

Comment: Thank you *so much* for your help and work on this!

I've implemented the algorithm you described, and will share it as a separate answer in a moment; since you've described the underlying algorithm, though, I'm happy to accept your answer.

The work I'm doing is for a small Shiny app, which will be BSD 3-Clause licensed for doing exploratory analyses on Signal XML backups. Given how far above-and-beyond you've gone here in volunteering your help, would you be interested in an authorship credit? If so, I can PM you with more details. In any case, thank you!

Comment: I've also posted example code for others to use following rensa's suggestion above re: converting emoji characters to names, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48154929/1940466

Comment: I'm not sure if SO has private messages, but you can hit me up on social media (https://rensa.co) to chat :)

Comment: Will do! : )

More information that can be relevant to future readers: I've learned that these character representations are called "surrogate pairs." Cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239432/handling-surrogate-pairs-while-parsing-xml-using-libxml2) re: parsing them (the authors of that post came to a similar conclusion as here).

Answer (score 2):

**JavaScript Solution**

I had this ***exact*** same problem, but needed the solution in JavaScript, not R. Using [rensa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3246758/rensa)'s [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48143046/4013327) *(hugely helpful!)*, I created the following code to solve this issue, and I just wanted to share it in case anyone else happens across this thread as I did, but needed it in JavaScript.

```
str.replace(/(&#\d+;){2}/g, function(match) {
    match = match.replace(/&#/g,'').split(';');
    var binFirst = (parseInt('0x' + parseInt(match[0]).toString(16)) - 0xd800).toString(2);
    var binSecond = (parseInt('0x' + parseInt(match[1]).toString(16)) - 0xdc00).toString(2);
    binFirst = '0000000000'.substr(binFirst.length) + binFirst;
    binSecond = '0000000000'.substr(binSecond.length) + binSecond;
    return '&#x' + (('0x' + (parseInt(binFirst + binSecond, 2).toString(16))) - (-0x10000)).toString(16) + ';';
});
```

---

And, here's a full snippet of it working if you'd like to run it:

```js
var str = '&#55357;&#56842;&#55357;&#56856;&#55357;&#56832;&#55357;&#56838;&#55357;&#56834;&#55357;&#56833;'

str = str.replace(/(&#\d+;){2}/g, function(match) {
 match = match.replace(/&#/g,'').split(';');
 var binFirst = (parseInt('0x' + parseInt(match[0]).toString(16)) - 0xd800).toString(2);
 var binSecond = (parseInt('0x' + parseInt(match[1]).toString(16)) - 0xdc00).toString(2);
 binFirst = '0000000000'.substr(binFirst.length) + binFirst;
 binSecond = '0000000000'.substr(binSecond.length) + binSecond;
 return '&#x' + (('0x' + (parseInt(binFirst + binSecond, 2).toString(16))) - (-0x10000)).toString(16) + ';';
});

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = str;

//  &#55357;&#56842;&#55357;&#56856;&#55357;&#56832;&#55357;&#56838;&#55357;&#56834;&#55357;&#56833;
//  is turned into
//  &#x1f60a;&#x1f618;&#x1f600;&#x1f606;&#x1f602;&#x1f601;
//  which is rendered by the browser as the emojis
```

```html
Original:<br>&#55357;&#56842;&#55357;&#56856;&#55357;&#56832;&#55357;&#56838;&#55357;&#56834;&#55357;&#56833;<br><br>
Result:<br>
<div id='result'></div>
```

My [SMS XML Parser](https://github.com/dynamiccookies/SMS-XML-Parser) application is working great now, but it stalls out on large XML files so, I'm thinking about rewriting it in PHP. If/when I do, I'll post that code as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented the algorithm [described by rensa above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48143046/1940466) in R, and am sharing it here. **I am happy to release the code snippet below under a [CC0 dedication](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/)** (i.e., putting this implementation into the public domain for free reuse).

This is a quick and unpolished implementation of rensa's algorithm, but it works!

```
utf16_double_dec_code_to_utf8 <- function(utf16_decimal_code){
  string_elements <- str_match_all(utf16_decimal_code, "&#(.*?);")[[1]][,2]

  string3a <- string_elements[1]
  string3b <- string_elements[2]

  string4a <- sprintf("0x0%x", as.numeric(string3a))
  string4b <- sprintf("0x0%x", as.numeric(string3b))

  string5a <- paste0(
    # "0x", 
    as.hexmode(string4a) - 0xd800
  )
  string5b <- paste0(
    # "0x",
    as.hexmode(string4b) - 0xdc00
  )

  string6 <- paste0(
    stringi::stri_pad(
      paste0(BMS::hex2bin(string5a), collapse = ""),
      10,
      pad = "0"
    ) %>%
      stringr::str_trunc(10, side = "left", ellipsis = ""),
    stringi::stri_pad(
      paste0(BMS::hex2bin(string5b), collapse = ""),
      10,
      pad = "0"
    ) %>%
      stringr::str_trunc(10, side = "left", ellipsis = "")
  )

  string7 <- BMS::bin2hex(as.numeric(strsplit(string6, split = "")[[1]]))

  string8 <- as.hexmode(string7) + 0x10000

  unicode_pattern <- string8
  unicode_pattern
}

make_unicode_entity <- function(x) {
  paste0("\\U000", utf16_double_dec_code_to_utf8(x))
}
make_html_entity <- function(x) {
  paste0("&#x", utf16_double_dec_code_to_utf8(x), ";")
}

# An example string, using the "hug" emoji:
example_string <- "test &#55358;&#56599; test"

output_string <- stringr::str_replace_all(
  example_string,
  "(&#[0-9]*?;){2}",  # Find all two-character "&#...;&#...;" codes.
  make_unicode_entity
  # make_html_entity
)

cat(output_string)

# To print Unicode string (doesn't display in R console, but can be copied and
# pasted elsewhere:
# (This assumes you've used 'make_unicode_entity' above in the str_replace_all
# call):
stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(output_string)
```

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47190794/1940466, which implements a possibly similar algorithm in PHP (I haven't looked closely enough at it to be sure how similar the two approaches are).

Answer (score 1):

Translated Chad's JavaScript answer to Go since I too had the same issue, but needed a solution in Go.

https://play.golang.org/p/h9JBFzqcd90

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    emoji := "&#55357;&#56842;&#55357;&#56856;&#55357;&#56832;&#55357;&#56838;&#55357;&#56834;&#55357;&#56833;"

    regexp := regexp.MustCompile(`(&#\d+;){2}`)
    matches := regexp.FindAllString(emoji, -1)

    var builder strings.Builder

    for _, match := range matches {
        s := strings.Replace(match, "&#", "", -1)

        parts := strings.Split(s, ";")
        a := parts[0]
        b := parts[1]

        c, err := strconv.Atoi(a)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        d, err := strconv.Atoi(b)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        c = c - 0xd800
        d = d - 0xdc00

        e := strconv.FormatInt(int64(c), 2)
        f := strconv.FormatInt(int64(d), 2)

        g := "0000000000"[2:len(e)] + e
        h := "0000000000"[10:len(f)] + f

        j, err := strconv.ParseInt(g + h, 2, 64)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        k := j + 0x10000

        _, err = builder.WriteString("&#x" + strconv.FormatInt(k, 16) + ";")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(html.UnescapeString(emoji))
    emoji = html.UnescapeString(builder.String())
    fmt.Println(emoji)
}
```